# Unable to boot Beaglebone Green Wireless with Debian 7.x

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboneblack

I'm unable to boot my `Beaglebone green wireless` from SD card having `Debian 7.8` Image. When I insert SD card into BBG, it won't blink, just one of the USR led lights up and nothing happens. Also I can't install Debian 7.8 into `eMMC`. There is no problem with `Debian 8.4`. Problem is not with SD card as I have tested same SD card with `Beaglebone Black` and I'm able to boot with that.

This happens only with `Beaglebone Green` and not with `Beaglebone Black`. Can anyone suggest a way to get it done.

Comment: As you don't provide any details of what goes wrong, I can only guess that the 7.8 Image you're trying predates the BBG. So it was never tested for it and possibly lacks *something* that makes it fail.

Comment: @TBR 7.8 Image is older than BBG so they must have tested it on BBG. I don't think there a point  making BBG incompatible with Debian 7.8. Also I'vs some details in my question.

Comment: You'd need to attach to the debug UART (serial port) using an appropriate cable to observe U-Boot and Kernel output. Sometimes those are referred to as "FTDI cables", as FTDI was the first to produce them, but they are basic USB to 3.3V UART adapters.

Comment: @TBR  On this [page](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images) there is no Debian 7.8 available for BBG. FTDI cable is a way to see what's going on in Kernel. I'll try that and update accordingly.

Comment: Why not use one of the 7.x Debian images that actually are specified to be usable for the BBG, on that page? It's all wheezy after all.